# How to find the index value of an object based on finding a property of an object within that object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Currently I am looping over this object to find the property:value pair I seek

```
var obj = [
   {thespecial:"cheese", taco:"none"},
   {thespecial:"lettuce", taco:"double"},
   {thespecial:"mustard", taco:"melty"}
]

$.each(obj, function(i,v){
   if(obj[i].thespecial == "lettuce")
   {
      //do some stuff..
   }
});
```

which works, however I have a case where I want to remove from the main obj the entire object that contains a match. That said, the index of the main object isn't in the same place. So I need to detect the index of the object that contains the match. Then remove it. Is there a way to detect from the main object the index of the match? I know if I were working with a simpler object or a simple array I could simply do indexOf, but I am not sure how to do that in this case.

Comment: Your declaration of `obj` isn't valid; it will cause a syntax error (`Unexpected token {`). Please correct your code, then update the question. Until then, it's hard to give you much direction.

Comment: You might want to use `$.grep` instead.

Comment: if `obj` is actually an array you have the index already as `i` in `each`. If this isn't the case then explanation of objective isn't clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `obj` is actually supposed to be an array since you added the tag `arrays`, just record a reference to your target `i` if you detect a match and delete it later.

```
var target = -1;

$.each(obj, function (i, v) {
    if (obj[i].thespecial === "lettuce") {
        target = i;
        //do some other stuff?
        return false; // break the loop if nothing else to do
    }
});

if (target >= 0) {
    obj.splice(target, 1); // remove item from array
}
```

Also assuming you only want to remove one item.

---

**Update**

If you need a way to remove various items from the "object" array, you may want a function like this:

```
function removeWithValue(val) {
    $.each(obj, function (i) {
        if (obj[i].thespecial === val) {
            obj.splice(i, 1); // remove item from array
            return false; // break the loop
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, this actually helped me come to the conclusion that this isn't the issue I am having. So the overall deal is its safe to assume the object is properly formed. What happens is my users have the ability to add/remove options from an overall list that contains sub features. Everytime they add something it adds to the master object `obj` in this case. But until they save if, they can continue to add and remove items. So what I am doing is, delete from the master object when they delete. The first time I loop over and a delete occurs I am fine, any subsequent deletes to the object break

Comment: since the objects index is no longer the same. A user adds three, index is 0, 1, 2.. removes something its 0,2.. adds two more things its 0,2,3,4 but since the loop is treating `i` as an incremental value removing an index is impossible if its the same incremental value of 1 in this example. The answer here helped me come to that conclusion now I just don't know how to get past that

Comment: The index won't matter in this case, the user is not deleting a specific index, they're deleting an item with a particular value. Yes the indices will change, but it will still work. Also you say it's safe to assume that the object is properly formed, but your code sample is not valid javascript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If your object format is correct then below code will help you

```
$.each(obj, function(i,v){
   if(obj[i].thespecial == "lettuce")
   {
      delete obj[i];
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to correct your object format like this:

```
var obj = [
    {thespecial: "cheese", taco: "none"},
    {thespecial: "lettuce", taco: "double"},
    {thespecial: "mustard", taco: "melty"}
];
```

then loop

```
$.each(obj, function (i, v) {
    if (obj[i].thespecial == "lettuce") {
        console.log(obj[i].taco); // your matched data here, perform your act
    }
});
```